# Control key remap not working in vim

Tags: macos, vim

I'm using a macbook pro with OS X 10.10.5 and vim 7.3.  I've got the following remap `inoremap <c-u> <esc>viwU<esc>ea`.  Obviously, I expect the word under the cursor to be capitalized after pressing Ctrl-u, but instead it pages up.  I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.  I see a few posts on remapping ctrl to cmd but I'd prefer to stick with cntrl - I use the same settings when working on a Windows machine.

As a note, I'm using a logitech keyboard, but it doesn't work on the mac keyboard as well.

Comment: Ummm. Sounds like you used it in normal mode instead of insert mode, which is where you defined the mapping.

Comment: You are absolutely right - that was dumb.  Works like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inoremap` creates an insert mode mapping. Using `<c-u>` in normal mode moves the page up.

Your mapping should work if you hit `<c-u>` in insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

`inoremap` will create an insert mode mapping.

In this case, you may use `noremap <c-u> <esc>viwU<esc>ea` to remap `c-u`.